# How to include a variable name in tkinter text="" attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, python-3.6

Basically I have an entry widget. A user (variable=username) inputs their name. On the next page, it shows text="Welcome username". If the user's name is, say, John, then I would like it to say "Welcome John". Whatever username is input I would like it to say "Welcome (variable=username)" if that makes sense.

Using tkinter with python3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is:

```
tkinter.Label(root, text='Welcome %s' % username).pack()
```

Comment: Wow thanks! Duh, I am an idiot. Also a noob. Lol i appreciate the quick response.